# How to preserve IPTC metadata of an image in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to resize (thumbnail) an image using PIL, the iptc data is lost.

What do I have to do preserve iptc data in the thumbnail image?

I saw there is a support of IptcImagePlugin in Pillow library but that's only for reading the iptc data of an image. How do I write the iptc data on an image after it is lost ?

Comment: Creating a new thumbnail image will lose *all* the metadata associated with the original image.  Unfortunately I don't know how to copy that metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe more of a work-around, but you can extract and insert IPTC data with both **exiftool** and **ImageMagick**.

That means you should be able to do it in Python with **exiftool** by adapting my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70529583/2836621). Or by using [wand](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.7/) which is a Python binding for **ImageMagick**. Failing that, I guess you could use Python `subprocess` module.

---

With **exiftool**, copy forward IPTC data from `original.jpg` to `new.jpg`:

```
exiftool -tagsfromfile original.jpg -IPTC:all new.jpg
```

In Python, that should look like this (untested):

```
import exiftool

# If  "exiftool" is not on your PATH, add the full path inside parentheses on next line
with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
   et.execute(b"-tagsfromfile original.jpg -IPTC:all", b"new.jpg")
```

Another way of doing this is to extract the IPTC data to a file and then patch those values into your PIL-created thumbnail:

```
exiftool original.jpg -b -IPTC > saved.iptc
exiftool '-IPTC<=saved.iptc' new.jpg
```

---

With **ImageMagick**, extract IPTC to file `extracted.iptc`:

```
magick original.jpg extracted.iptc
```

And now insert into `new.jpg`:

```
magick new.jpg -profile extracted.iptc withprofile.jpg
```

Or, copying forward the IPTC from `original.jpg` into `new.jpg` to produce `result.jpg` just the same as above but in one fell swoop without creating a temporary file and relying on a `bash` shell *"process substitution"*:

```
magick new.jpg -profile <(magick original.jpg iptc:-) result.jpg
```