# Get image rating attribute

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I would like to get the image `Rating` attribute with Python and/or Windows CMD for search the user's favorite images in a directory. As I know when the user pick the image for a favorite, the Windows automatically add at least one star.

[image]

I tried `WMIC` and `os.stat()` but these functions/commands didn't content the needed attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `exiftool`:

```
exiftool -rating YOURIMAGE.JPG
```

If that gets the rating you seek, you can adapt to Python like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70708133/2836621).