# How can I copy metadata to modified image in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, exiftool

I am using a python script to extract the metadata from an image and then make a watermark based on one of the parameters in the metadata. Since the watermarked image is, essentially, a new image, the original metadata is lost.

currently, I am using pyexiftool's get_metatdata() method to collect a dictionary of all the metadata but, I am unsure of how I can inject these metadata back into the new watermarked image. I am using PIL to make and add the watermark. Something like a "put_metadata()" method would be ideal but, that seems unlikely. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `watermarkedIimage.save(outputName, exif=originalImage.getexif())`

Comment: I think you need to look at the parameters to the `save` function, specific to the format you're saving to.

Comment: Make sure you are using the [newer, updated fork of pyexiftool](https://github.com/sylikc/pyexiftool#documentation) and use the [`copy_tags()`](https://sylikc.github.io/pyexiftool/reference/3-alpha.html#exiftool.ExifToolAlpha.copy_tags) function.

Comment: Any luck with my suggestion?

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell - Thank you yes, I tried that but it appears that some of the tags I need to preserve are XMP tags they didn't seem to be included in the exif data. I am trying to use pvexiv2 and am having some (limited) success... I was planning to post an update but, life...

Comment: Maybe try with `exiftool` just in your Terminal at first like this `exiftool -tagsfromfile ORIGINALIMAGE -xmp WATERMARKIMAGE`. If that works, you can do it in Python like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70708133/2836621

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [copy_tag()](https://sylikc.github.io/pyexiftool/reference/3-alpha.html#exiftool.ExifToolAlpha.copy_tags) function. For example:

```
import exiftool

def add_watermark_and_save_img(original_img, new_img):
    # your code here

original_img = "/path/to/open/original_img"
new_img = "/path/to/save/new_img"

add_watermark_and_save_img(original_img, new_img)

exiftool.ExifToolAlpha().copy_tags(original_img, new_img)
```