# Replace/add Tiff image tags using Pillow from one file to another

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am new to python. I have two tiff images. One with correct tags (`source.tif`) while the other with incorrect ones (`target.tif`).

I am able to read the tags of the correct image using the following python script.

```py
from PIL import Image
from PIL.TiffTags import TAGS
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None

# open image
sourceimg = Image.open('images/source.tif')

# extract exif data
exifdata = sourceimg.getexif()

# get dictionary of tags
for tag_id in exifdata:
    # get the tag name, instead of human unreadable tag id
    tag = TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)
    data = exifdata.get(tag_id)
    # decode bytes 
    if isinstance(data, bytes):
        data = data.decode()
    print(f"{tag:25}: {data}")
```

How can I take these tags from the source and overwrite/add only certain parameters in the `target.tif`?

Comment: I don't have access to a machine for a few more days, but look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70708133/2836621 and here   https://stackoverflow.com/a/70529583/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell I saw exiftool but wasn't sure if it works on Tiff tags or on Exif meta data. I need to change the TIFF tags to match the processing software's specifications for a TIFF image.

Comment: It would help if you provided an image with some tags you wish to retain, some tags you wish not to retain and also one or two tags not present that you wish to add - including values for the new ones. Then your question would be far more concrete. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell the format we are trying to get is as per Genepix software. The specifications are provided in the following link. https://support.moleculardevices.com/s/article/GenePix-File-Formats Note - but for example purposes you can use any example `tagsToAdd` and `tagsToKeep`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`TiffImageFile.tag_v2`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/plugins.html#PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile.tag_v2) dict can be modified and used as the `tiffinfo` argument when [saving](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#saving-tiff-images) the target image:

```py
from PIL import Image

sourceimg = Image.open("source.tif")
targetimg = Image.open("target.tif")

# Get the TIFF tags from the source image
tiffinfo = sourceimg.tag_v2

# Add or modify any tags you want (using the tag number as key)
# Tag number 270 is the ImageDescription tag
tiffinfo[270] = "Example image"

# Save the target image with the correct tags
targetimg.save("target.tif", tiffinfo=tiffinfo)

print(targetimg.tag_v2[270])
>>> Example image
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution. Are the tags obtained as indexes of numbers e.g. `270`, anyway to look for it on the based of name e.g. `ImageDescription`?

Comment: @Coola The corresponding tag names are documented in the TIFF tag specifications, you can find them [online](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/content/tiff_tags.shtml).

Comment: I was able to find most tags. But there are some tags which are tags like `ImageJMetaData`, which is not in the website link you provided. How to handle those?

Comment: @Coola I could not find that tag in any official specification, but it was mentioned in GitHub issue [#291](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/291) and it does appear in the [`TiffTags.TAGS_V2`](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/fc7319318e4fb50503de2dc0d4d8ba2bdc29bbb2/src/PIL/TiffTags.py#L79-L220) dict.

Comment: Thanks. One last question - is there a way to access the TiffTags dictionary from PIL? That way, one can probably just iterate over the required tags right?

Comment: @Coola Yes, `TAGS_V2` can be imported from `PIL.TiffTags`. The tag names are the first elements of the value tuples.