# Replacing TIF image tags using Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, metadata, tiff

I am trying to implement the code shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71385332/replace-add-tiff-image-tags-using-pillow-from-one-file-to-another) to modify the TIF image tags for an image. I need to do this for thousands of images but can't get it working yet for one.

The code from the solution is as follows, but when I try I get a KeyError when executing the last line.

```
from PIL import Image

sourceimg = Image.open("source.tif")
targetimg = Image.open("target.tif")

# Get the TIFF tags from the source image
tiffinfo = sourceimg.tag_v2

# Add or modify any tags you want (using the tag number as key)
# Tag number 270 is the ImageDescription tag
tiffinfo[270] = "Example image"

# Save the target image with the correct tags
targetimg.save("target.tif", tiffinfo=tiffinfo)

print(targetimg.tag_v2[270])
>>> Example image
```

How can I iterate through a series of photos to modify the metadata (tif tags) while getting around this error? Thanks!

Comment: You asked for the file to be saved with the new tag info, but that doesn't change the existing object.  You would need to do `Image.open` again.

Comment: @TimRoberts does that mean `tiffinfo` is a *copy* of the tags and not a reference to the original dictionary inside the image object?  That's not usually how Python works.

Comment: @TimRoberts never mind my earlier comments, I didn't realize that the question was asking about *two* completely separate image objects - `sourceimg` and `targetimg`.  You're absolutely correct, resaving the file does **not** update the existing object, you need to open it again.

Comment: If you have thousands of images, consider writing a function that does just one image. Then test it, then use multiprocessing to run that function on all images.

Comment: Note that it is generally very simple, convenient and performant to edit EXIF and TIFF tags with `exiftool`. See also `tiffset` which is delivered with `libtiff` for setting tags easily.