# Set Photometric tag in TIFF without losing other metadata

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff, libtiff

I have TIFFs that do not have the Photometric tag set. I want to do something like this in PIL

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("image.tiff")
im.tag[262] = 1
im.save("out_image.tiff", tiffinfo=im.tag)
```

But since the 262 tag is not set, the image isn't valid and won't open in PIL to set it.

I have tried using LibTIFF

```
tiffset -s 262 1 image.tiff
```

It sets the photometric tag, but doesn't retain the GPS tags in my images.

Is there a way to add the 262 tag without losing the other metadata associated with the image?

Edit:

The error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in 
> im = Image.open('D:/image.tiff')
> File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\Image_dev\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2896, in open
> "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
> PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'D:/image.tiff'

Comment: Please share one of your problematic TIFFs, you can use Google Drive or Dropbox. Also please clarify the exact error message your code generates - it seems odd you can't open a file because a tag is missing.

Comment: Counterpoint: please don't use google drive or dropbox, but a github repository, or a known image from a reputable source (like an open source project). That said, did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71385332/replace-add-tiff-image-tags-using-pillow-from-one-file-to-another?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace/add Tiff image tags using Pillow from one file to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71385332/replace-add-tiff-image-tags-using-pillow-from-one-file-to-another)

Comment: @Woodford It doesn't, unfortunately, because it requires the images to be loaded into PIL, which I cannot do with my images.

Comment: Try [tifftools](https://pypi.org/project/tifftools/).

Comment: @ cgohlke 

`tifftools set -y -s Photometric 1 D:/image.tiff`

This sets the photometric tag, but also clears the GPS metadata

Comment: Ar you referring to the GPS IFD tag #34853? Is that tag properly typed as an IFD?

Comment: @cgohlke Yes. It turns out LibTiff did do what I needed, but it made it so the GPS data was not listed under Properties > Details of the image. I was able to use tifftools to confirm that the 34853 tag was indeed still there.

`info = tifftools.read_tiff('image.tiff')`
Thanks, everyone, for your suggestions.