# Add tif tags to big/pyaramidal tif outside of PIL

Tags: python, image, tiff

I'm attempting to add tif tags (specifically Dec 280 and 281, MinSampleValue and MaxSampleValue, respectively) to a pyramidal and multichannel image, meaning that it isn't compatible with PIL (this could be either BigTiff or OME) in python. Does anybody have a way to do this and/or an example? Tools for modifying tags seem to be relatively available, but adding additional tags is more challenging outside of PIL. To clarify, I would like to use a package outside of PIL.

For psuedo code:

```
load('example.tiff')

for ifd in example.tiff:
    tiftags['MinSampleValue'] = 0
    tiftags['MaxSampleValue'] = 255

save('revised_example.tiff')
```

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimum reproducable example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can't tell from your question whether you want to use PIL or not? Nor what you have tried. Nor why you believe something is incompatible with PIL. Could you click [edit] please and clarify. Thank you.

Comment: Try Python binding for `exiftool`. Example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70529583/2836621

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Python [bindings](https://pypi.org/project/PyExifTool/) for exiftool, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70529583/2836621).

Or, you can use the small set of [tools](http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/tools/tiffset.html) that get installed with `libtiff`, specifically:

```
tiffset -s 280 XXX YOURIMAGE.TIF
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment Mark. I tried your suggestion and am getting the following error: "No space for 280 tag".  Any clue as to what this means? I'm assuming that there currently is not a 280 tag and this method can only edit current tags, not add new tags?

Comment: Maybe you can share a link to your problematic TIFF via Dropbox or Google Drive or somesuch.