# Pillow cannot extract all exif information

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif

I am trying to use Pillow to get exif data for photos, but it looks like it does not return all that should be available. Using the simple code:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

def get_exif():
  i = Image.open('IMG_0780.JPG')
  info = i.getexif()
  return {TAGS.get(tag): value for tag, value in info.items()}
print(get_exif())
```

will return

```
{'ResolutionUnit': 2, 'ExifOffset': 192, 'Make': 'Apple', 'Model': 'iPhone SE', 'Software': '11.3', 'Orientation': 1, 'DateTime': '2018:04:29 20:32:21', 'YCbCrPositioning': 1, 'XResolution': 72.0, 'YResolution': 72.0}
```

But when I open the same image with gthumb, it shows me a lot more:

[image]

in my case I am especially interested in the OriginalDateTime, but there is a lot of other data that I cannot get with Pillow

```
Pillow 9.3.0
Python 3.10.6 (main, Aug 10 2022, 11:40:04) [GCC 11.3.0]
```

Comment: IMHO, `exiftool` is the *"gold standard"* for dealing with EXIF and other metadata, either at commandline or in Python. Example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70529583/2836621

Comment: I'm actually experiencing same error. The Pillow package no longer provides the full exif data or something?

Comment: use https://pypi.org/project/PyExifTool/

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue, but for camera serial number. I would prefer not using exiftool and am curious why Pillow can't seem to extract this information (which is present).

Answer (score 1):

Further data is nested under sections called IFDs, one of them is the 'Exif SubIFD' which is pointed to by the `ExifOffset` you see in your output. To get the items under that:

```
from PIL import ExifTags

img_exif = image.getexif()
for ifd_key, ifd_value in img_exif.get_ifd(ExifTags.Base.ExifOffset).items():

    ifd_tag_name = ExifTags.TAGS.get(ifd_key, ifd_key)
    print(f" {ifd_tag_name}: {ifd_value}")
```

To loop around all tags in all IFDs you could do this:

```
from PIL import ExifTags

IFD_CODE_LOOKUP = {i.value: i.name for i in ExifTags.IFD}

for tag_code, value in img_exif.items():

    # if the tag is an IFD block, nest into it
    if tag_code in IFD_CODE_LOOKUP:

        ifd_tag_name = IFD_CODE_LOOKUP[tag_code]
        print(f"IFD '{ifd_tag_name}' (code {tag_code}):")
        ifd_data = img_exif.get_ifd(tag_code).items()

        for nested_key, nested_value in ifd_data:

            nested_tag_name = ExifTags.GPSTAGS.get(nested_key, None) or ExifTags.TAGS.get(nested_key, None) or nested_key
            print(f"  {nested_tag_name}: {nested_value}")

    else:

        # root-level tag
        print(f"{ExifTags.TAGS.get(tag_code)}: {value}")
```

Comment: This does extract more data in my images where I'm able to extract EXIF data. However, it does not work for PNG files saved by a Windows snipping tool. I'm still getting no data from them.